# SVG SMIL animateMotion only triggers once

Tags: javascript, svg, smil

I have a SVG map of air flight destinations for Prague airport. I'd like to animate a circle along a path to each of these airports.

Grab the code [here](http://expirebox.com/download/6eeaeffde396192eab3cee1f5d0d28a4.html) (sorry for this, doesn't work on jsfiddle).

The code that takes care of "flight" animation looks as follows:

```
function animate() {
    var flights = {
        100: ["travel-svo", "travel-svo"],
        600: ["travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-fra",
                 "travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-nap"],
        620: ["travel-ams", "travel-ams"],
        700: ["travel-lhr", "travel-lhr", "travel-lhr", "travel-lhr", "travel-lhr"],
        710: ["travel-cdg", "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg"],
        805: ["travel-gva"],
        810: ["travel-vie", "travel-vie", "travel-vie", "travel-vie"],
        850: ["travel-ams", "travel-ams", "travel-ams"],
        855: ["travel-svo"],
        930: ["travel-beg", "travel-beg"],
        935: ["travel-muc", "travel-muc", "travel-muc"],
        945: ["travel-sof", "travel-sof"],
        950: ["travel-fco"],
        955: ["travel-cdg", "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg",
                 "travel-cdg", "travel-cdg"],
        1010: ["travel-mad", "travel-mad", "travel-mad", "travel-mad", "travel-mad"],
        1015: ["travel-svo", "travel-svo"],
        1025: ["travel-zrh"],
        1030: ["travel-dxb", "travel-dxb", "travel-arn"],
        1035: ["travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-fra", "travel-fra",
                "travel-fra"],
        1040: ["travel-led", "travel-led"]
    };

    var circle = function(coef, flight_id) {
        var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var svgDocument =document;
        var motion = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns,"animateMotion");
        var shape  = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");

        motion.setAttribute("begin", "path_ani.end");
        motion.setAttribute("dur", "10s");
        motion.setAttribute("path", document.getElementById(flight_id).getAttributeNS(null, "d"));
        motion.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#" + flight_id);

        shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  1*coef);
        shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "1f78b4");
        shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "1f78b4");
        shape.setAttribute("id", "airplane-" + flight_id);
        shape.appendChild(motion);
        document.getElementById("airplanes").appendChild(shape);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        var time = 100;

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var f = flights[time];
            var counts = {};

            if (f) {
                // count unique items
                for(var i = 0; i < f.length; i += 1) {
                    var num = f[i];
                    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
                }

                for (var flight in counts) {
                    circle(counts[flight], flight);
                }
            }
            time += 5;
            // stop
            if (time > 1040) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 50);
    }, 12000);
}
```

The first animation (first key of `flights` object) starts as it should, while the rest appear at 0,0 (top left corner of the screen) and don't move at all. I have no idea what might be causing this, as the `circle()` function defines new `<animateMotion>` element for every unique flight.

**UPDATE:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngqemLh5/2/)

Comment: @RobertLongson question updated

Comment: That's not simpler. Something thats a few dozen lines not 2000 lines.

Comment: @RobertLongson it's the whole world, you don't need to read 2K lines. The issue seems to be somewhere in the javascript (bottom of the file), not the svg itself.

Comment: `motion.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#" + flight_id);` is wrong. No idea whether fixing that makes it work though. Needs to be setAttributeNS with an additional namespace first argument.

Comment: If it was wrong, even the first animation wouldn't trigger and still it does.

Comment: I give up then, the problem is likely elsewhere and its unlikely you'll find someone to look for your needle unless you get rid of most of the hay.

Comment: @RobertLongson jsfiddle link updated with a simplified svg version (no countries, no grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `begin` attribute for those elements is set to the past.
(`path_ani.end` already triggered before you create the  two last `animateMotion` elements).

As I don't know the expected behavior, I'll let you figure out what to do
(Either find why the two last planes are created after, or what's the correct value to insert into their `begin` attributes.)

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngqemLh5/3/)** with `begin` attributes set to `15s`

Comment: Interesting idea! However, postponing the animation with `path_ani.end+15s` doesn't make a difference. What makes me wonder is why all the circles (except the first one) appear at 0,0 coordinate.

Comment: If you hardcode it to `15s`, they will all trigger and none will be set to `cx="0"`, `cy="0"` (default values since not modified by `animateMotion`)

Comment: ps: `path_ani.end+15s` is likely to produce nothing good either, since `path_ani.end` will never trigger again. So it's like you set `undefined + 15s`

Comment: Hey, that's great, it actually works! However, animations seem to start somewhere in the middle of the path. It's caused by SMIL trying to interpolate their position from those 15 secs. That seems to be the last obstacle in my way.

Comment: Yes, as I told you in the answer, you have to either find why your last 2 planes are created after the first one, or to find the good value (In your position, I'd tend for the first option though). But since it's a mess of timeouts, and it's not part of the question, I'll let you find this out.

Comment: They should be created after as they take off at different times (100, 600). It should be just fine to sum those 15 secs with a current value of `time` var.

Comment: IMHO, One better approach would be to create them all at load, and only set the `begin` to `path_ani.end+time`